# Transaction with Persistent

Tags: mysql, haskell, yesod

I'm using Persisent with a MySQL database and it seems transaction are not working.

I'm doing something similar to

```
runDB $ do
    insertMany something
    error "should rollback"
    insertMany somethingElse
```

I expect `something` to not be in the database. The call to `error` should rollback the transaction, but when I do it, `something` is inserted in the database. Am I missing something ? (I've checked that autocommit is set to 0, and it is).

Comment: How did you check the autocommit setting? (It is a per-connection setting (and defaults to enabled), so if you use a different client, it might not have the same value). How did you check that the rows are there? (If you use the same connection, the rows will still exist until you close it)

Comment: @Solarflare: I added `rawExecute "show variables like 'autocommit'` and print the result. That might be indeed irrelevant. However, looking at the code (`Persistent`) it looks like autocommit is set to false and runDB (which comes from Yesod scafholding) run thing in a transaction. I wonder if it's a problem in the actual MySQL package (used by Persistent).